# R - Call a function from function name that is stored in a variable?

Tags: r

I'm writing some R code and I want to store a list of Function names and what they are for in a dataframe, and then query that dataframe to determine which function to call, but I can't figure out how to do this, or if it's even possible.

As a basic example, let's assume the function name is just stored as a string in a variable, how do I call the function based on the function name stored in that variable?

```
MyFunc <-function() {
    # Do some stuff...
    print("My Function has been called!!!")
    return(object)
}

FuncName <- "MyFunc()"
Result <- FuncName
```

I need to make

```
Result <- FuncName
```

Work the same as

```
Result <- MyFunc()
```

Also, passing objects, or other variables, to the functions is not a concern for what I am doing here, so those () will always be empty.  I realize passing variables like this might get even more complicated.

Comment: Is `eval(parse(text = Result))` what you want?

Comment: If the answer is parse() you should usually rethink the question.  -- Thomas Lumley, R-help (February 2005)

Comment: ... Furthermore, one should not be attempting to evaluate a function call as a character string in the first place.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use `get()` with an additional pair of `()`.

```
a<-function(){1+1}                                                                                                  
var<-"a"

> get(var)()
[1] 2
```

Comment: Thank you!  Get was exactly what I was looking for.  Plus that extra set of () on the end allows me to pass parameters to the function should I need to(not a requirement now, but nice to have as an option if I need it).

Comment: Be careful using `get` for this purpose.  If there is another object in the global environment with the same name as the function (e.g., `c <- 1`), then `get("c")` will return the value of the other object (e.g, `1`).  Try `do.call()` or `match.fun()` instead.  These two approaches will find only functions (not other objects) associated with the given name (e.g., `"c"`).

Answer (score 4):

To get a function from its name, try `match.fun`, used just like `get` in the answer provided by @Alex:

```
> a <- function(x) x+1
> f <- "a"
> match.fun(f)(1:3)
[1] 2 3 4
```

To call a function directly using its name, try `do.call`:

```
> params <- list(x=1:3)
> do.call(f, params)
[1] 2 3 4
```

The advantage to `do.call` is that the parameters passed to the function can change during execution (e.g., values of the parameter `list` can be dynamic at run time or passed by the user to a custom function), rather than being hardwired in the code.

Why do I suggest `match.fun` or `do.call` over `get`?  Both `match.fun` and `do.call` will make sure that the `character` vector (`"a"` in the above examples) matches a function rather than another type of object (e.g., a numeric, a data.frame, ...).

Consider the following:

```
# works fine
> get("c")(1,2,3)
[1] 1 2 3

# create another object called "c"
> c <- 33
> get("c")
[1] 33

#uh oh!!
> get("c")(1,2,3)
Error: attempt to apply non-function

# match.fun will return a function; it ignores
# any object named "c" that is not a function.
> match.fun("c")(1,2,3)
[1] 1 2 3

# same with do.call
> do.call("c", list(1,2,3))
[1] 1 2 3
```